# How can i enable true ToolStripMenuItem in form1 when backgroundworker completed his operation in a new class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 constructor i did:

```
viewResponsesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
```

In a new class i have a backgroundworker:

```
void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allLinksToParse.Count; i++)
    {
        GetResponsersFN(allLinksToParse[i]);
    }
}
```

And completed:

```
void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I need when the backgroundworker completed so in form1 to make:

```
viewResponsesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
```

But how do i know in `form1` when the `backgroundworker` completed in the new class ?

Comment: Grant right i did it this way sbuscribed the completed event in form1 after made the backgroundworker public in the class. It's working now with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give reference to your `form1` instance. You can do that in your `new classes' constructor`. Add a new private variable for the `form1` in your new class:

`private Form form1;`

Then set the reference in your classes constructor:

```
newClass(Form form1Reference)
{
   this.form1 = form1Reference;
}
```

Then you can use this in your `BackgroundWorker's Completed-event`:

```
this.form1.viewResponsesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
```

Make sure that you've set the `viewResponsesToolStripMenuItem`'s `Modifiers` to `Public`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use create form1 object and use it in bgw_RunWorkerCompleted to enable toolstripmenuitem.

```
form1 obj= new form1();
void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      obj.viewResponsesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Try using this.It should work.

Comment: You right too but needed to set the viewResponsesToolStripMenuItem to public first.